# Can't figure out why SMTP email does not work to the same domain it's sending from

Tags: php, email, smtp

I have a PHP customer input form which sends out SMTP mail to the company hosting the form. For some reason the emails are not reaching the recipient's email. If I substitute in any other email address not on the domain it works out fine. I can also list multiple addresses on the To: line and the others will get the email but not the desired info@ email address. I cannot change the sending domain since my web hosting won't send mail when they are mismatched. I thought that it might have to do with the sending email address and receiving being the same so I changed the From: address to "onlineform@" instead of "info@" but that made no difference.

I'm perplexed as to what's happening here. I can send email directly from any other account to the "info@" email address and that works fine. I've asked them to check their client *and* server junk mail folders and they are both clean. Any ideas on what's going on or how to further diagnose the issue? I've simplified the code down to the relevant parts below and the snippet code does the same thing.

```
<?php
$email_to = "info@domain.tld";
$email_subject = "Subject line here";
$email_message = "Email body here.";

$headers = 'From: onlineform@domain.tld'."\r\n".
'Reply-To: noreply@domain.tld'."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could have something to do to the server's mail policy. You may be *telling* the server that the message is being sent from whatever@domain.tld, but you are not *proving* it.

Have you tried to send using SMTP authentication? Not sure this is actually the real problem, but it worth testing.

Also, I recommend you to ***always*** use mail solutions instead of using the plain php mail() function. I've used [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php) for a long time and not only it works fine, it always eased the boring process of sending e-mails through php.